# Why does this for-loop always return the square of the number and not the exponent value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, for-loop

I tried to code this into python:
essentially it is a exponent calculator
so for exp(2, 5) it should return 2<sup>5</sup>

```
def exp(num, pow):
    for i in range(0, pow, 1):
        num1=num*num
    print(num1)
print(exp(2, 5))
```

why won't it work?

I expected it to work but it always gives the square of the number.

Comment: 1. `print` is not the same as `return`. 2. You get `num1` equal to `num` squared because that's how you define it -- `num1 = num * num`. Why would `num1` be anything else?

Comment: `num*num` gives the square of `num`, and `num1` is not updated in your loop.

Comment: I suggest indenting your `print(num1)` so that it is inside the for loop and prints on each iteration. Now run your code and see what happens. How does this differ from what you expect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Exponential in python is calculated with (**). You can simply do this:

```
def exp(num, pow):
    return num**pow
print(exp(2, 5))
```

and this should return the value to the power

Comment: thanks, I started out with python just today.

Comment: 1. The question is "Why doesn't their code work", not "how do I get it to work". 2. Questions as basic as this usually have duplicates. Please look for a duplicate and flag/vote to close instead of answering duplicate questions. See the "well-asked questions" section of [answer]

Answer (score 3):

Each iteration of the loop just multiplies `num` by itself, *once*.

Sticking to your existing code as much as possible, you can modify your function to be like this:

```
def exp(num, pow):
        original_num = num

        for i in range(1,pow,1):
            num = num * original_num
        print(num)
```

Comment: I suggest using a different variable to store the results of the muliplication. Re-using a variable for a different purpose is a bad habit to get into. It will eventually cause a bug that will be difficult to find.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `num1=num1*num` or `num=num*num` instead of `num1=num*num`.

If you do `num1=num*num`, the num1 will always contain the num^2 no matter how long the loop takes.

```
num1 = num
for i in range(1,n):
    num1=num1*num
return num1
```

or

```
for i in range(1,n):
    num=num*num
return num
```

Comment: i tried num=num*num and failed but this works, thankss

Comment: Ok @crimson-wind. Please kindly accept this answer (and give an upvote) if you regard this answer helpful. thanks